# Why is binary search using this weird thing to calculate middle?

Tags: algorithms, binary-search

I noticed that in many books calculation of midpoint for binary search uses this:

```
int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
```

Why not use

```
int mid = (left + right) / 2;
```

instead?

Comment: The only "advantage" is that your calculation never exceeds the value of `right`.

Comment: @fade2black, I don't see how is it possible to exceed value of right in second case.  If `left` = `right`, then `(2 * right) / 2` = `right`.

Comment: @rus9384 `left + right >= right`, intermediate values I mean. Kind of take actions against overflow.

Comment: @fade2black, I think, this is an answer.

Comment: Perhaps to avoid overflow. This seems like a programming question and so off-topic here.

Comment: This is [indeed](https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) the answer.

Comment: Why can't we do mid = high + (low-high)/2 ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because `left + right` may overflow. Which then means you get a result that is less than `left`. Or far into the negative if you are using signed integers.

So instead they take the distance between `left` and `right` and add half of that to left. This is only a single extra operation to make the algorithm more robust.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose your 'low' and 'high' are 16 bit unsigned integers.
That means, they can only have a maximum value of 2^16=65536.
Consider this, 
low = 65530
high = 65531

If we added them first, (low+high) would end up being junk since that big a number (131061) cannot be stored in a your 16-bit integer.
And so, mid would be a wrong value.

Comment: Yeah david,, I found out a lot people saying overflow overflow on the different forums but couldn't understand what they really mean to say.. After i found out the example,, my confusion was cleared..

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57703680/130427) answer gives a practical example of why the `l + (r-l)/2` calculation is necessary.

In case you are curious how the two are equivalent mathematically, here is the proof. The key is adding `0` then splitting that into `l/2 - l/2`.

```
(l+r)/2 =
l/2 + r/2 =
l/2 + r/2 + 0 =
l/2 + r/2 + (l/2 - l/2) =
(l/2 + l/2) + (r/2 - l/2) =
l + (r-l)/2
```